# Unexpected behavior of CCASE in SBCL (compared to CASE and ECASE)

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Why is there a difference in behavior between **ecase** (or **case**) and **ccase** in the examples below? **ecase** is behaving normally, unlike **ccase**. Tested with **SBCL** version 2.0.1. I didn't find an explanation after a quick look at the specs (CLTL2).

```
(ecase 'dos
  ((i uno) 1)
  ((ii dos) 2)
  ((iii tres) 3))

2
```

```
(ccase 'dos
  ((i uno) 1)
  ((ii dos) 2)
  ((iii tres) 3))

; in: CCASE 'DOS
;     (SETF 'DOS
;             (SB-KERNEL:CASE-BODY-ERROR 'CCASE ''DOS #:G680
;                                        '(MEMBER I UNO II DOS III TRES)
;                                        '(I UNO II DOS III TRES)))
; --> LET* FUNCALL 
; ==>
;   (SB-C::%FUNCALL #'(SETF QUOTE) #:NEW1 #:DOS3)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   The function (SETF QUOTE) is undefined, and its name is reserved by ANSI CL so
;   that even if it were defined later, the code doing so would not be portable.

; ==>
;   (LET* ((#:DOS3 DOS)
;          (#:NEW1
;           (SB-KERNEL:CASE-BODY-ERROR 'CCASE ''DOS #:G680
;                                      '(MEMBER I UNO II DOS III TRES)
;                                      '(I UNO II DOS III TRES))))
;     (FUNCALL #'(SETF QUOTE) #:NEW1 #:DOS3))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::DOS
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     (SETF QUOTE)
;   Undefined variable:
;     DOS
;   caught 2 WARNING conditions
2
```

Comment: `ccase` takes a *keyplace*, not a *keyform* like `case` and `ecase` that is used with `setf` when invoking the `set-value` restart when nothing initially matches. See https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ccase` needs a *place* which can store a value, not a value.  In other words the first argument to `ccase` must be a form which is a valid first argument for `setf`.

That's because, in the case where no clause matches, a restartable error is signalled with a `store-value` restart which will assign a value to the place which is the first argument, and then retry the whole `ccase` form.

`'x` is not such a form: you can't say `(setf 'x ...)`.

Here is a toy version of `ccase`, called `continuable-case` which demonstrates what the expansion of `ccase` might be.  This probably misses things, but it's enough to demonstrate where it stores a value into the place.

```
(defmacro continuable-case (place &body clauses)
  (when (assoc-if (lambda (k) (member k '(otherwise t))) clauses)
    (error "can't have a default clause"))
  (let ((name (make-symbol "CONTINUABLE-CASE"))
        (retry (make-symbol "RETRY"))
        (value (make-symbol "VALUE"))
        (v (make-symbol "V"))
        (expected-type `(member ,@(mapcan (lambda (clause)
                                            (let ((key (first clause)))
                                              (typecase key
                                                (cons
                                                 (copy-list key))
                                                (t (list key)))))
                                          clauses))))
    `(block ,name
       (tagbody
        ,retry
        (return-from ,name
          (let ((,value ,place))
            (case ,value
              ,@clauses
              (otherwise
               (restart-case
                   (error 'type-error
                          :datum ,value
                          :expected-type ',expected-type)
                 (store-value (,v)
                   :report "set a new value and retry"
                   :interactive (lambda ()
                                  (format *query-io* "~&new value: ")
                                  (finish-output *query-io*)
                                  (list (read *query-io*)))
                   (setf ,place ,v)
                   (go ,retry)))))))))))
```